# Filtering data in a table for a required condition

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Don't bother about the title, I am unable to think through the exact question. Please find my question below.

I am trying to filter out the data in such a way that, the result set should not contain the make and model corresponding to the given year. For example if I gave 2014, the result set should not contain "Acura - ILX and BMW - X5". It should return remaining make and models.

Below is the table structure.

```
Id  | Make    | Model     | Year
---------------------------------
1   | Acura   | ILX       | 2012
2   | Acura   | ILX       | 2013
3   | Acura   | ILX       | 2014
4   | Acura   | ILX       | 2015
5   | Acura   | RL        | 2012
6   | Acura   | RL        | 2013
7   | Acura   | RL        | 2015
8   | BMW     | X5        | 2012
9   | BMW     | X5        | 2013
10  | BMW     | X5        | 2014
11  | BMW     | Q7        | 2011
12  | BMW     | Q7        | 2012
13  | BMW     | Q7        | 2013
14  | BMW     | Q7        | 2015
```

Expected result when 2014 is given.

```
Id  | Make    | Model     | Year
---------------------------------    
5   | Acura   | RL        | 2012
6   | Acura   | RL        | 2013
7   | Acura   | RL        | 2015   
11  | BMW     | Q7        | 2011
12  | BMW     | Q7        | 2012
13  | BMW     | Q7        | 2013
14  | BMW     | Q7        | 2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague helped me to figure out the quick response for the above scenario. The query is

```
select make,model,group_concat(year ORDER BY year ASC) as yearList from apd_cars 
group by model,make 
having yearList NOT like '%2014%' 
order by make,model;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (Make,Model) NOT IN 
(
    SELECT Make, Model FROM `table` WHERE Year = 2014
);
```

Fiddle Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ae10/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that answer. But it is taking so much time to execute. For returning 418 records it took nearly 1 min 30 sec. And my table contains 5429 records and storage engine is MyISAM. The records count will increase over a period of time. Can we have any other quick queries?  I tried group by make, model at the end (main query not in the sub query) which reduces the count to 24, but still it took 1 min 24 secs.

Comment: I don't know the reason behind that performance, but i am currently 30% at mysql, so your colleague are probably right! :)